# doinbackground() in async task not working properly

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, onscrolllistener

I am fetching some data from API and presenting each item as a `RecyclerViewPager slide`. So, I have made an `async task` inside `onScrollListener` to check scroll actions and when the user slides 5 items `asynctask` fetches the Items of page 2 and in the `doInBackGround` function the data will be added to the array and array will be added to the `recycler view pager`.

Everything works fine but I need to stop scrolling at 5 slide for a few seconds(Minimum 5 sec) or else the `recyclerView` won't show the 2nd page slides.

How to solve this problem. This is the code I am using for the `onScrollListener` and `asyncTask` functions.

Code :

```
 private void initRecycler(){

       final RecyclerViewPager mRecyclerView = (RecyclerViewPager) findViewById(R.id.list);

// setLayoutManager like normal RecyclerView, you do not need to change any thing.
       final LinearLayoutManager layout = new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
       mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layout);

//set adapter
//You just need to implement ViewPageAdapter by yourself like a normal RecyclerView.Adpater.
       RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(ImageUrls, ImageNames, ImageDesc, this);
       mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

       mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

           @Override
           public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
               super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

              visibleItemCount = layout.getChildCount();
              totalItemCount = layout.getItemCount();
               firstVisibleItem = layout.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
//               int aaa = totalItemCount - visibleItemCount;
//               int bbb = firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold;
//               Log.d("tag" ,"totalItemCount : " + totalItemCount + "|  visibleItemCount : " + visibleItemCount);
              Log.d("tag" ,"totalItemCount : " + totalItemCount + "|  previousTotal : " + previousTotal);
               Log.d("tag", "firstVisibleItem :" + firstVisibleItem + " | totalItemCount :" + totalItemCount);
               if (loading) {
                   if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                       loading = false;
                       previousTotal = totalItemCount;
                   }
               }
               if (!loading && (firstVisibleItem + 5)
                       == (totalItemCount)) {

                   Log.i("Ya!", "end called");
                   page += 1;
                   String url = "http://url.in/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?page="+page+"&_embed";
                   Log.d( url ,": ");
                   // Do something
                   final OkHttpClient client2 = new OkHttpClient();
                   final Request request2 = new Request.Builder()
                           .url(url)
                           .build();
                   @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak") AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> asyncTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
                       private static final String TAG = "SlideFragment";

                       @Override
                       protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

                           try {

                               Response response2 = client2.newCall(request2).execute();

                               if (!response2.isSuccessful()) {
                                   Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: REsponse Un Successfull - 56");
                                   response2.body().close();
                                   return null;

                               }
                               String Data2 =  response2.body().string();
                               response2.body().close();
                               return Data2;
                           } catch (Exception e) {
                               e.printStackTrace();
                               Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: Exceptione on line63");
                               return null;
                           }

                       }

                       @Override
                       protected void onPostExecute(String Data2) {

                           super.onPostExecute(Data2);
                           if (Data2 != null) {
                               Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute: 188 LINE");
                               try {
                                   JSONArray json = new JSONArray(Data2);
                                   for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
                                       JSONObject post = json.getJSONObject(i);
                                       String title = post.getJSONObject("title").getString("rendered");
                                       String description = post.getJSONObject("excerpt").getString("rendered");
                                       String imgURL = post.getJSONObject("_embedded").getJSONArray("wp:featuredmedia").getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("media_details").getString("file");
                                       String imagUrl = "http://url.in/wp-content/uploads/" + imgURL;
                                       ImageNames.add(title);
                                       ImageDesc.add(description);
                                       ImageUrls.add(imagUrl);
                                       Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute: arrayList Created" );
                                   }


                               }catch(JSONException j){
                                   j.printStackTrace();
                                   Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute: on line 121");
                               }
                           }
                       }
                   };
                   asyncTask.execute();
                   loading = true;
               }
           }
       });

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should cancel task manually before making another request, as one task can only be executed once according to rules given in the documentation

[image: See Last Rule]

[image: To Cancel A Task]